# Running test methods one after another in TestNG

Tags: methods, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, testng

I m using Eclipse + Selenium WebDriver + TestNG

This is my class structure :

```
class1
{
@test (invocation count =4)
method1()

@test (invocation count =4)
method2()

}
```

my testing.xml file :

```
<classes>
<class name="tests.class1">
<methods>
<include name="method1" />
<include name="method2" />
</methods>
</class>
</classes>
```

When running through my current testing.xml, the order of the tests is:
method1
method1
method1
method1
method2
method2
method2
method2

But I want the tests to be run in the following order:
method1
method2
method1
method2
method1
method2
method1
method2

Please guide me to achieve the desired result. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you using Java, right?

Answer (score 4):

Look up "`dependsOnGroups`" in the [documentation](http://testng.org).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use "priority" of TestNG as:

```
@Test(priority = -19)
public void testMethod1(){
//some code
}
@Test(priority = -20)
public void testMethod2(){
//some code
}
```

[Note: The priority for this test method. Lower priorities will be scheduled first]

So, in the above example testMethod2 will be executed first as -20 less than -19

You can visit for more details:
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a lot of methods to make it. An Example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ABC {

    @Test(invocationCount=12)
    public void uno(){
        System.out.println("UNO");
    }
    @AfterMethod()
    public void sec(Method m){
        if(m.getName().equals("uno"))
        System.out.println("SEC");
    }
}
```

And suite:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test" parallel="none" >
    <classes>
      <class name="aaa.ABC">
          <methods>
              <include name="uno">
          </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite>
```

Remeber, if you use `dependsOnMethod` then thoes method will be executed after all invocation.
For example:

```
@Test(invocationCount=3)
public void uno(){
    System.out.println("UNO");
}
@Test(dependsOnMethods={"uno"})
public void sec(){

    System.out.println("SEC");
}
```

with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test" parallel="none" >
    <classes>
      <class name="aaa.ABC">
          <methods>
              <include name="uno"/>
                 <include name="sec"/>
          </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite>
```

will give:

```
UNO
UNO
UNO
SEC

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

And if you test your tests please use `verbose ="3"` in suite conf. example:

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none" verbose="3">
```

Cause this is turning on full logs.