# How to preserve group order in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I have two classes that each implement something differently but the tests are the same for both. Each class does some things that would affect the other class if they run in parallel, so they can't run in parallel. (that's the rationale behind the code below)

If you run the class Both, see below, in Eclipse, as a TestNG test, one would expect it to run tests test1 and test2 of class ClassAAA first and then the same test methods for ClassBBB, because ClassBBB's group annotations specify that it depends on ClassAAA's annotation.
However, what you find out is that, seemingly, TestNG has a different way of looking at it, and, "seemingly",  it ignores the group order and runs the tests of the two clases in parallel.

```
class Both {

    @Test(groups={"base"})
    public static abstract class BothBase {

        @Test public void test1() { System.out.println("test1"+name()); }               
        @Test public void test2() { System.out.println("test2"+name()); }

        protected String name() {
            String s = getClass().getName();
            s = s.substring( 1 + s.lastIndexOf("$"));
            return " - " + s;
        }
    }

    @Test(groups={"gr1"})
    public static class ClassAAA extends BothBase { }

    @Test(groups={"gr2"},dependsOnGroups={"gr1"})
    public static class ClassBBB extends BothBase { }
}
```

The output is:

```
test1 - ClassAAA
test1 - ClassBBB
test2 - ClassAAA
test2 - ClassBBB
```

One way, which i don't like, to try to "force" it to honor the desired group order, is to add a dummy test method to the leaf classes, as follows:

```
    @Test(groups={"gr1"})
    public static class ClassAAA extends BothBase { 
        @Test public void dummyTestMustBeInAllLeavesToEnforceGroupOrder() { 
            System.out.println("dummyTestMustBeInAllLeavesToEnforceGroupOrder"+name());
        }   
    }

    @Test(groups={"gr2"},dependsOnGroups={"gr1"})
    public static class ClassBBB extends BothBase { 
        @Test public void dummyTestMustBeInAllLeavesToEnforceGroupOrder() { 
            System.out.println("dummyTestMustBeInAllLeavesToEnforceGroupOrder"+name());
        }   
    }
```

This still doesn't completely do what one would expect. The output is:

```
test1 - ClassAAA
test2 - ClassAAA
test2 - ClassBBB
dummyTestMustBeInAllLeavesToEnforceGroupOrder - ClassAAA
test1 - ClassBBB
dummyTestMustBeInAllLeavesToEnforceGroupOrder - ClassBBB
```

This means that it started running the tests of ClassBBB before finishing the tests of ClassAAA.
I don't like the fact that i have to add a dummy/unrelated method to each, to get TestNG to understand that they cannot be run in parallel. In fact, i don't care which class runs first... And, i didn't really accomplish what i wanted because they are still running in parallel.

The stupidest way to do this, which would accomplish my goal is to move the tests from the base class to each of the leaf classes - is that how you are suppose to do these things in TestNG?

Is there another way of doing that? i'm sure someone is going to suggest priorities - but again, that does not convey the true intention - i don't have any priority - just don't want them to run in parallel. Also i don't want to write XML files...

Answer (score 0):

This problem is coming due to static inner classes. Try below code you will get required output

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


    @Test(groups={"base"})
    public abstract  class BothBase {

        @Test public void test1() { System.out.println("test1"+name()); }               
        @Test public void test2() { System.out.println("test2"+name()); }

        protected String name() {
            String s = getClass().getName();
            s = s.substring( 1 + s.lastIndexOf("$"));
            return " - " + s;
        }
    }

    @Test(groups={"gr1"})
      class ClassAAA extends BothBase { }

    @Test(groups={"gr2"},dependsOnGroups={"gr1"})
      class ClassBBB extends BothBase { }
```

Comment: How do i then run it in eclipse? i tried (in Run configuration...) selecting the Groups button but whatever groups i type and then run, it always executes 0 tests

Comment: move the classes to separate files and make them public again

Answer (score 0):

Many ways

Simplest - priority

Bit harder( groups)

Check testng manual(for ex. this http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/testng-tutorials/).

Comment: I've done it with groups - didn't work. what exactly should i look for in the testing manual?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503743/running-test-methods-one-after-the-other-in-testng and http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-groups-example/