# How to use method dependency between two classes in testng?

Tags: selenium, methods, automation, dependencies, testng

I have 2 test classes one is for testing the register functionality of a website and another is for login.

```
public class TestResister{
@test
public void testSignup(){
}
}

public class TestLogin{
@test
public void testLoginUser(){
}
}
```

I want that when i run testLoginUser() function it automatically call testSignup().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Something like the following:

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void testMethod1(){
//some code
}
@Test(priority = 2)
public void testMethod2(){
//some code
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503743/running-test-methods-one-after-the-other-in-testng). Lower priority will execute first. However, any any condition, ***Test dependency* is not best practice. Each and every test should be designed to perform independently. Think about what will happen to test with priority 2 if test with priority 1 fails.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem correct, but you just need to call the method.

```
public class TestRegister{
    public void testSignup(){
    }
}


public class TestLogin{
    public void testLoginUser(){
        TestRegister.testSignup();
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class TestLogin{
    public void testLoginUser(){
        TestRegister tstregister = new TestRegister();
        tstregister.testSignup();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that i can call the method using other class's object but i want to know that is it possible to do it using annotations ? like dependsOnmethod in annotation.

Comment: Ah that wasn't clear to me. Maybe Saifur's answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, what if the registration is already done? will it fail ?

I think you are looking for the following attribute.

You can use the attributes dependsOnMethods or dependsOnGroups, found on the @Test annotation.

There are two kinds of dependencies:

- Hard dependencies. All the methods you depend on must have run and
  succeeded for you to run. If at least one failure occurred in your
  dependencies, you will not be invoked and marked as a SKIP in the
  report.
- Soft dependencies. You will always be run after the methods you
  depend on, even if some of them have failed. This is useful when you
  just want to make sure that your test methods are run in a certain
  order but their success doesn't really depend on the success of
  others. A soft dependency is obtained by adding "alwaysRun=true" in
  your @Test annotation.

Here is an example of a hard dependency:

```
@Test
public void signup() {}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "singup" })
public void login() {}
```

In this case if singup fails login wont run. If you want to still run login then add "alwaysRun=true". Then login will run irrespective of signup is successful or not.
For more please look up http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: Hi Shamik  I have created the framework like everytime i run signup it creates a new user so the condition will never raise of already done registration.Another thing is i want hard dependency because the same user is used in both method so if signup will fail login will also fail.But my question is I have these 2 methods in different class so how can i use method dependency.

Comment: OK! I have never tried to see if depends on works across classes. Did u try it ? Did it not work ?

Comment: Yehhh... Just found a solution.

Comment: The method was not visible to other class thats why it was failing I just extended register class in login class and it worked.